# How is index modified by dataframe.sort_values()

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe that i want to sort on one of my columns (that is a date)
However I have a loop i am running on the index (`while i<df.shape[0]`), I need the loop to go on my dataframe once it is sorted by date. 
Is the current index modified accordingly to the sorting or should I use `df.reset_index(`) ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: I am not sure it is necessary because the question is quite general, what is the impact of sort_value on the index of the dataframe, I can give you some sample but they are basic and I don't think they are relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but a simple check shows that `sort_values` does modify the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','c','b'], 'y':[1,3,2]})
df = df.sort_values(by = 'x')
```

Yields:

```
   x  y
0  a  1
2  b  2
1  c  3
```

And a subsequent:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Yields:

```
   x  y
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
```